# Xamarin.forms Navigation Drawer on button click

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation-drawer

How to display navigation drawer in xamarin forms on button / icon click.
I have a button in my detail page and on click i want navigation drawer ISPresented to be true. how can this be done? Thanks in advance

Comment: masterPage.IsPresented = true / false;

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options here, the most obvious and simple to implement is to use the [MessagingCenter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/). Since you can't access the `MasterDetailPage` directly and you want to avoid coupling.

At the point where you create your `MasterDetailPage`, subscribe to an event like this:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage> (this, "OpenMaster", (sender) => {
    masterPage.IsPresented = !masterPage.IsPresented;
});
```

Now on the button that you want to trigger your functionality with, implement sending this message like this:

`MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage> (this, "OpenMaster");`.

Now, I don't know any details about your code, so I can't help you with where to put this exactly and you probably need to replace some things like `MainPage` to correspond with your code. But this should give you an idea.

Comment: I am not getting where should i put this code. help me out in that.

Comment: i am having two class one Navigation Drawer that has the drawer and the other one is detail page that is named 'Booking'. Now i have a button in booking class from where i want to open the drawer

Comment: Put the subscribe in your drawer page, this can access the `IsPresented` property. Put the send in your button code on the booking class.

Comment: I have used this **MessagingCenter.Subscribe<NavigationDrawer> (this, "OpenMaster", (sender) => {
    IsPresented = !IsPresented;
});**

Comment: Like I said, you probably need to replace `MainPage` with a name of your own. Please update your question with relevant code, including class names and specify what is not working

Comment: My Navigation Drawer i have put this code **MessagingCenter.Subscribe<NavigationDrawer> (this, "OpenMaster", (sender) => { IsPresented = !IsPresented; });** and in my booking class i have put **MessagingCenter.Send<Booking>(this, "OpenMaster");**

Comment: The `MessagingCenter.Subscribe<NavigationDrawer>` should also have Booking. So `MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Booking>`. This specifies the class that is sending a message and at the subscriber side the class name to subscribe for.

Answer (score 0):

Gerald It worked

At the point where you create your MasterDetailPage, subscribe to an event like this:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage> (this, "OpenMaster", (sender) => {
    masterPage.IsPresented = !masterPage.IsPresented;
});
```

Now on the button that you want to trigger your functionality with, implement sending this message like this:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage> (this, "OpenMaster");.
```

Comment: Thanks!  Gerald Versluis

Comment: On adding master detail page i am getting unwanted space at top how to remove it???

Answer (score 0):

try this simplest solution

```
((MasterDetailPage)App.Current.Mainpage).Master.IsPresented = true;
```